# Porque tengo este error de iTextSharp? Rebuild failed: Input string was not in a correct format.; Original message: PDF startxref not found

Tags: itextsharp, c#-8.0

Este es mi codigo y da como resultado este error: Rebuild failed: Input string was not in a correct format.; Original message: PDF startxref not found

```
bool Ret = true;
    try
    {
        var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileName);
        reader.Close();
        Ret = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Ret = false;
    }

    return Ret;
```